# Keyed access in PIC config settings for the WWDT

Tags: pic, watchdog

I'm playing around with the settings for the windowed watch dog timer (WWDT) for the [PIC18F24K40](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18(L)F24_25K40%2028-Pin%20Low-Power%20High-Performance%20MCU%20with%20XLP%20Technology%2040001843D.pdf).

In chapter 3.7.3 (page 37) about device configuration, the DT Window Select bits are briefly described, but there is no explanation in chapter 9 (page 106) (which treats the WWDT).

Searching internet on "keyed access" only give me more datasheets different PIC's, but none of them have it explained in more detail.

So, what does "keyed access" mean?
And what does "Software control of WINDOW" mean? And how can I manipulate the window in software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Microchip data sheet 40001843D mentions "keyed access" for bits in the WDTCON1 register in error. Access to these bits are read-only when CONFIG3 bits WDTCWS are not 111. When they are 111 the WDTCON1 can be written at any time.

The term "keyed access" usually means executing a specific sequence of instructions to enable write access to bits in a Special Function Register. See section: `11.1.2 NVM Unlock Sequence` for an example of how this works for writing to program flash or EEPROM memory.

Comment: I fail to see where the datasheet is in error. The things you write are also mentioned in the datasheet. On page 37, the datasheet only mentions software control of WINDOW when WDTCWS=111. I think the terms are misleading as you cannot control the WINDOW within software.

Comment: Thanks for explaining keyed access. I still wonder how this keyed access would be implemented

Comment: @Huisman, The error in the data sheet is referencing "keyed access" for bits in the WDTCON1 register then NOT DESCRIBING the unlock method. For other PIC18F parts with the same windowed watchdog timer there is no mention of "keyed access" to these bits. There are several Microchip data sheets that document things that are not in the actual device.

Comment: @Huisman, The PIC18F24K40 windowed watchdog timer has few features that can be changed during execution. The watchdog timer timeout duration is a feature that can only be set in a configuration word during programming. Only WDT enable or disable and the percent of the timeout duration the WDT window is open can be changed while your code is running.